# Adding Templates in Maven

Tags: maven, directory, copy

I have a folder src/resource/templates with .xlsx and .docx files. I am using maven and how is it possible to copy files from that folder into jar file?

Comment: Put those files into `src/main/resources` and they will automatically being copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer using maven copy.

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <!-- here the phase you need -->
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/classes/report/resource/Templates</outputDirectory>
          <resources>          
            <resource>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/report/resource/Templates</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>              
        </configuration>            
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add more resource directories to maven project. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

For example:

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/resource/templates</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

**EDITED** added clarification:

If you now have file `src/resource/templates/example.xlsx` it should be on jar's root.

File `src/resource/templates/report/resource/Templates/example.xlsx` would be copied to jar as file `report/resource/Templates/example.xlsx`

Comment: So this is the code for resources `<resource>
        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>` So * should include everything and templates is a sub folder but for some reason it didn't maybe you may explain it? file types are xlsx, xls, doc, docx and txt @ikettu

Comment: `<include>*</include>`means all files. You have to use for example `<include>**/*.txt</include>` to recursively find all txt files.

Comment: On the proposed solution whole subtree from `src/resource/templates` should be included recursively as it is to jar during assambly.

Comment: I have used **/** but it didn't do the job, doesnt this one say include everything everything?